# The logic behind Ractive.DEBUG minify assertion

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I saw in Ractive docs this line of code:

`Ractive.DEBUG = /unminified/.test(function() {/*unminified*/});`

Can you explain the logic behind this ?
The function should have the same value, despite whether it has inline comments or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minification will remove the comment from the code so the function becomes `function() {}` when regex `test` calls `.toString()` on the function, thus yielding `false`.

Without minification, the regex test will find the occurrence of `unminified` and therefore DEBUG will be `true`

Comment: this is a great hack.

Comment: full props to go to Rich Harris https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/pull/1813#issuecomment-79733487